# adding onclick event to input element in large html table causes the page to render slow. how to improve the performace?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, gridview, repeater

adding onclick event to input element (type=image) in large html table (around 2000 rows) causes the page to render slow (in IE 9). the input element appears once for each row. if i remove the onclick it renders fast. onclick calls a javascript function. is there an alternate way to attach the event that would not slow down rendering? javascrpt function is in a .js file that is included in the head and it makes an ajax call to a different page to load a div and display it as a popup dialog (jquery-ui dialog).

```
<table class="tables_wrapper" style="width: 1450px; table-layout:fixed">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 150px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 30px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
        <col style="width: 100px; word-wrap:break-word; word-break: break-all; " />
    </colgroup>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="repeater1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name1%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name2%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name3%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name4%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name5%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name6%></td>
                <td><input type="image" src="images/tick.png" alt="" onclick='ShowName("<%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name7 %>", this); return false;' /></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name8%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name9%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name10%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name11%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name12%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name13%></td>
                <td><%# ((User)Container.DataItem).Name14%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us how you are attaching the event handler.

Comment: also, show us the placement of your function in respect to the html (is it above or below it).

Comment: Added the code and more details

Comment: i aslo updated the code based on your table.but i cannot check in ie 9 .. try the jsfiddle.-

Answer (score 2):

Use event delegation, which in this case means adding a `click` event handler to the whole table and examining the element from which the event originated to decide what action to take.

For example:

```
yourTable.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input" && target.type == "image") {
        alert("Image input clicked");
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/s5bDL/

Answer (score 0):

add just one eventhandler;

js

```
function handle(e){
 var img=e.target||window.event.srcElement;
 img.type!='image'||alert(img.src);
 //img.type!='image'||(YOURJQUERYFUNCTION())
}
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].onclick=handle;
```

html

```
<table>
 <tr><td><input type="image" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50"></td><td>a2</td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="image" src="http://placekitten.com/50/50"></td><td>b2</td></tr>
</table>
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/rE9zd/